# tkinter python - place() a widget to the top-right corner

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to `place()` my widget on the top-right corner of the window

I can't use `pack()` or `grid()` here.. (due to some reasons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `relx` and `rely` (not necessary for this case, could also use `y`) and set the `anchor` to `'ne'` (north east - top right):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label


root = Tk()

lbl = Label(root, text='Hello World')
lbl.place(relx=1, rely=0, anchor='ne')

root.mainloop()
```

It basically positions the top right corner of the widget to a relative (relative to its master) `x` of `1` which basically is the right side of the window and `y` to `0` which is top. Basically the top-right corner of the widget is placed in the top-right corner of the window